# Whats the fastest way to install XCode on a virtual machine where the host already has XCode?

Tags: vmware, xcode

I have a macbook pro with XCode and VMWare running on it.  I've created a mac VM on that machine, and would like to install XCode.  Downloading via the store takes forever, I was hoping I could avoid that.  I read somewhere that I should be able to copy the XCode directory from the Applications folder of the host machine to the Applications folder of the VM, but I haven't been able to make that work.

Be gentle, I am very new with mac computers.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Either this way: (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6406451/1502563))

> "I simply copied "/Applications/Install Xcode.app" from one machine to
>   the other after the first machine downloaded from the App Store ($4.99
>   version). It worked fine."

Or this way: (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398055/1502563))

> "I am stumped by other answers here - I have just downloaded XCode
>   4.3.2 for Lion (AFAIK latest at the moment) from this site:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
>
> You only need a valid AppleID (free of charge) developer account. No
>   credit card whatsoever."

Comment: That solution takes about a day with my wifi connection.  Looking for something faster.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Maybe this is where my "new at mac" kicks in.  How exactly would I copy xcode.app across machines?  I tried right-click copying the file from /applications to a shared drive, and it complains that it can't copy some files.

Comment: Try zipping/archiving xcode by using stuffit or http://www.izip.com/ then move it to the virtual machine.

Comment: Moving the already installed xcode folder _might_ work, but do not expect any command line tools that were included with xcode to work. This might be where your "new at mac" kicks in but it's also where my initial "just install it the regular way" kicks in. Unexpected errors may and probably will occur now or later.